# Why not create my own semantic elements in HTML5?

Tags: css, html, semantics

I've learnt HTML and the basics of CSS only recently and am enjoying the liberty of finally being web literate. One thing puzzles me, with the usefulness (literally and semantically) of elements in HTML5 such as

```
<footer>
```

etc why dont we just create and define our own elements such as

```
<price>
```

or

```
<icon>
```

instead of giving standard ones classes or defining divs all the time which seems confusing in comparison? It seems CSS has no problem styling these (in my tests anyway) like anything else providing I state whether display is inline or block etc.

Is this a totally standard thing to do I have just stupidly realised or am I missing a major downfall with this here?

Comment: Several existing questions deal with the same issue, see also e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211394/when-to-use-custom-html-tags

Answer (score 2):

Because:

1. Semantics only do any good if the user agent (browser, search engine, etc) understands them
2. If you make up your own elements and a set of semantics, then someone else (including the W3C) may introduce their own element with the same name but with different semantics and user agents would interpret your element "incorrectly".